# Zoom into Leaflet Map Based on User Inputs

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to figure out how to zoom into a map based on user inputs. I have started with the map of the US and then trying zooming into a specific location based on zip code and number of miles:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Starbucks Locator"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       textInput("zip","Zip Code:", value = "18101"),
       sliderInput("radius",
                   "Radius",
                   min = 1,
                   max = 25,
                   value = 15),
       actionButton("go", "Submit")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
       leafletOutput("myMap")
    )
  )
))
```

This is the Server Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ZipRadius)
library(leaflet)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    data  <- reactive({x <- readRDS("Starbucks.rds")})
  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    df    <- data()
    m     <- leaflet(data = df) %>% 
             addTiles() %>%
             addMarkers(lng = ~Lon, lat = ~Lat)

  })
  eventReactive(input$go, {
    zip_include  <- zipRadius(input$zip, input$radius)
  })
  leafletProxy("myMap") %>% fitBounds(~min(zip_include$longitude), ~min(zip_include$latitude),
                                      ~max(zip_include$longitude), ~max(zip_include$latitude))
})
```

I am using the ZipRadius package to find the which zip codes are `input$distance` away from `input$zip`. Then I want to zoom into the input zip code as the center and the bounds defined by the radius (`input$distance`). The original `leaflet` map works, but the `leafletProxy` is where I am having my issue. Any thoughts on how to do this? I am trying to use `fitbounds` since it can take into account minimum and maximum latitudes and longitudes. I think the issue may be with the `eventReactive`, but not sure how to test it. The dataset is available here at [github](https://gist.github.com/dankohn/09e5446feb4a8faea24f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your server code.

1. You don't need to create your data in a reactive expression. As you only upload it once (I guess you won't change the coords or add another row).
2. Your `renderLeaflet` function can be simplified
3. **Instead of using `eventReactive` use `observeEvent`.** This function is triggered when you press the `go` button. In the observer you have to add all the actions that should be triggered by the button click. So you also have to insert the `leafletProxy` function here.
4. Remove the `~` symbol in the `fitBounds` function. You are already pointing to the `zip_include` dataset in `fitBounds`.

**Working server (with provided csv)**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  data  <- read.csv("c:/starbucks_us_locations.csv")
  names(data) <- c('Lon', 'Lat')
  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({leaflet(data) %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~Lon, lat = ~Lat)
  })

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    zip_include  <- zipRadius(input$zip, input$radius)
    print(zip_include)
    leafletProxy("myMap") %>% fitBounds(min(zip_include$longitude), min(zip_include$latitude),
                                        max(zip_include$longitude), max(zip_include$latitude))
  })
})
```